# Consider a collection of $24$ animals, $10$ of whom (randomly chosen) have been tagged.

Tags: probability

Consider a collection of $24$ animals, $10$ of whom (randomly chosen) have been tagged. Suppose that $8$ of the animals (randomly chosen) are recaptured. What is the probability that $4$ of these have been tagged?

Does binomial probability have to be used for this?

Comment: Are the $8$ recaptured with or without repetition?

Comment: @saulspatz it is without repetition

Comment: This is a little different than a problem where you have 8 trials and each has a $\frac{10}{24}$ chance of being tagged because the proportions change as you remove animals with each trial. Instead, you could just calculate how many ways you can create a group of 4 tagged animals, 4 untagged animals, and then how many groups of 8 in general. Also, it would change if "4" means "exactly 4" or "at least 4".

Answer (score 2):

It's just the number of ways to choose at least $4$ animals from the tagged ones divided by the number of ways to choose $8$ animals from $24$.  You might choose $4$ tagged animals and $4$ untagged ones, or $5$ tagged and $3$ untagged, and so on.

You'll use binomial coefficients in your calculations, but it's not a binomial probability distribution.

In details it is:

$$P=\frac{\binom{4}{10}\binom{4}{14}+\binom{5}{10}\binom{3}{14}+\binom{6}{10}\binom{2}{14}+\binom{7}{10}\binom{1}{14}+\binom{8}{10}}{\binom{8}{24}}$$

Comment: (+1) The name for this kind of distribution is the Hypergeometric Distribution

Comment: so it would be 4/10 divided by 8/24?

Comment: @pat no! read the answer carefully.

Comment: @pat You don't use probabilities at all in the calculations.  You just count combinations.  All sets of recaptured animals are equiprobable, so you just divide the number of successes (set with at least 4 tagged animals) by the totals number of events (sets of 8 recaptured animals.)

Answer (score 0):

A complicated way to do a problem of this nature would be to imagine that you are performing a series of experiments. You first are capturing an animal out of twenty-four with some probability of being tagged, then you are capturing an animal out of twenty-three with some probability of being tagged that is conditional upon the result of the previous experiment, and so on. It can be useful to bear in mind that the expected proportion of tagged animals in some random collection of recaptured animals should be the same as the proportion of tagged animals to the entire population.